# Combine multiple if statements with multiple properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking into using my loop to combine and narrow down this piece of code into maybe a switch statement or other methods, how would I be able to achieve that? This is what I have so far which has worked for me but I also have other `items[i].ApplicationType` such as 'OneDrive', 'Teams', etc..

```
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Windows' && items[i].RequestType == 'Single User' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'OneDrive')
    {
        ODwindows += 1;
    }
    else if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Windows' && items[i].RequestType == 'Single User' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'Teams')
    {
        Teamswindows += 1;
    }
    else if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Mac' && items[i].RequestType == 'Single User' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'OneDrive')
    {
        ODmac += 1;
    }
    else if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Mac' && items[i].RequestType == 'Single User' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'Teams')
    {
        Teamsmac += 1;
    }
    else if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Both' && items[i].RequestType == 'Team' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'OneDrive')
    {
        ODboth += 1;
    }
    else if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Both' && items[i].RequestType == 'Team' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'Teams')
    {
        Teamsboth += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: ES6 `.reduce()` might be useful, check its usage here: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/simplify-your-javascript-use-map-reduce-and-filter-bd02c593cc2d#fd38

Comment: I see this as two levels. The first simply checks for `ComputerType` being `Windows` or `Mac`. Then, in each of those `true` branches you have nested `switch` statements that check for the second condition.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: do you have other value than the above checked?

Comment: @NinaScholz, Nope that is it .. Which means if it's Windows/Mac it's single user based on application while Team also has "both"

Comment: This seems like a refactoring problem, and off topic for the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take an object with the different types and count by nested properties.

```
var count = {
        'Single User': {
            Windows: {
                OneDrive: 0,
                Teams: 0
            },
            Mac: {
                OneDrive: 0,
                Teams: 0
            }
        },
        Team: {
            Both: {
                OneDrive: 0,
                Teams: 0
            }
        }
    };

for (let { RequestType, ComputerType, ApplicationType } of items) {
    count[RequestType][ComputerType][ApplicationType]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a key for each unique combination of `ComputerType`, `RequestType` and `ApplicationType` separated by `_`. Then use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get each count to variables:

```
const output = {};

items.forEach(o => {
    const key = [o.ComputerType, o.RequestType, o.ApplicationType].join('_')
    output[key] = output[key] + 1 || 1
})

const {
    ['Windows_Single User_OneDrive']: ODwindows, 
    ['Windows_Single User_Teams']: Teamswindows, 
    ['Mac_Single User_OneDrive']: ODmac, 
    ['Mac_Single User_Teams']: Teamsmac, 
    ['Both_Team_Teams']: ODboth, 
    ['Both_Team_Teams']: Teamsboth
} = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const items = [{ComputerType: "Windows", RequestType:"Single", ApplicationType: "OneDrive"}]
    const countObj = items.reduce((accum, item) => {
      const { ComputerType, RequestType, ApplicationType } = item
      const key = `${ComputerType}_${RequestType}_${ApplicationType}`
      return { 
        ...accum,
        [key]: accum[key] ? accum[key] + 1 : 1
      }
    }, {})
    console.log(countObj)
```